# Chrome extension событие на alt+кнопка мыши

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, chrome-extension, расширения

Мне нужно, чтобы **jQuery** `$(document).on("mousedown", "...` сработал, если я нажму <kbd>alt</kbd> и . например <kbd>левую</kbd> или <kbd>правую</kbd> кнопку мыши, ( может или <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>кнопка мыши</kbd>, или <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>кнопка мыши</kbd>)... В **manifest.json** я не могу указать только <kbd>alt</kbd>... Также проблема в том, что на событие <kbd>shift</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>mouse Left button</kbd> открывается новая вкладка или окно. Как быть?

Как либо отменить запуск нового окна или таба, или сделать событие на <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>mouse left button</kbd>? С нажатым <kbd>Alt</kbd> **jquery** событие не срабатывает(....

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант #1** - используем свойство [MouseEvent.altKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/altKey), определяющее зажатали клавиша <kbd>alt</kbd> или нет и возвращает `true` или `false` соответственно:

```js
$(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (e.altKey) {
    console.log('alt+mouse');
  } else {
    console.log('mouse');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Вариант #2** - используем булевый флаг для определения нажатия клавиши <kbd>alt</kbd>:

```js
var altPress = false;
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 18) {
    altPress = true;
  }
}).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 18) {
    altPress = false;
  }
});

$(document).on('mousedown', function() {
  if (altPress) {
    console.log('alt+mouse');
  } else {
    console.log('mouse');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Не работает=( просто mouse- работает.

Comment: @AchiveArchive При нажатии alt+лкм все работает отлично

Comment: и на этой странице , ни в одном браузере, не работает с alt+лкм,

Comment: @AchiveArchive может вы не ту кнопку вместо alt жмете?